# Disable parenthesis matching in emacs

Tags: emacs, parentheses

When I'm typing in emacs, in particular when I'm editing a LISP file, emacs automatically matches parentheses for me. This would be fine, except that it *doesn't let me delete a parenthesis if it would cause a parenthesis imbalance.*  I suppose there might be people out there who find this a pleasant feature, but to me it's just terrible. I'm fine with it automatically writing a closing parenthesis for me, but I want to be able to delete a parenthesis when I want. It does something similar for quotes as well. This is really obnoxious! How do I stop it?

Comment: Recursively bisect your init file to find out what the culprit code is. As @js indicates, it is no doubt caused by `paredit.el` or a similar library. Just remove  the code from your init file that loads the culprit library or turns on the mode (e.g. `paredit-mode`) that is causing this behavior. Or just turn the mode off, if you want to continue loading the library for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emacs doesn't do that by default, that sounds like [ParEdit](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit). You might be able to derive from the installation description how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

The matching (and strict pairing/balancing) is usually a great feature. But sometimes there are cases where you need to intervene. Yes, you can turn off `electric-pair-mode` and `paredit-mode` and whatever similar modes you happen to have turned on. But the simplest way to deal with a rogue paren (or bracket or quote, etc) I have found is to "force-insert" its match right next to it. So if your point is sitting at a `)` (which you want to delete), then that means to insert a `(` is done with: `C-q (`. Now when you backspace, it will delete the pair.